# Can anyone solve this?

Tags: cipher, puzzle-identification

My cousin sent me this today. I am totally confused with these characters.
[image: Puzzle Image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **LETS PLGY** in [pigpen cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher)

which is a typo, should be

> **LETS PLAY**